# Runaway Ladda button - won't stop

Tags: javascript, ladda

I'm trying to use a Ladda progress indicator button. The spinner starts fine, but when I run a setTimeout to simulate another function, it never stops afterward.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ladda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/ladda.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="btn" class="ladda-button" data-color="gray" data-style="expand-right">Fred!</button>

    <script src="dist/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/ladda.min.js"></script>

    <script>

      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {

        var l = Ladda.create(document.querySelector('.ladda-button'));
        l.start();
        var  endIt = setTimeout(stopIt, 5000);
      }

      function stopIt() {
        l.stop();    // Also tried Ladda.stopAll();
        alert("End it All!");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on how to stop this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

The variable `l` does not exist in the `stopIt`-function.

```
<script>

  // Ladda variable needs to be put outside of click event or
  // the stopId-function won't be able to use it.

  var l = Ladda.create(document.querySelector('.ladda-button'));

  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    l.start();
    var endIt = setTimeout(stopIt, 5000);
  }

  function stopIt() {
    l.stop();    // Also tried Ladda.stopAll();
    alert("End it All!");
  }

</script>
```